# Nested Views with crossroads.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, crossroadsjs

I am trying to create a "tabbed details view" for a given entity and I need it to be deep linked with the url/hash. The hard part is I want the data to be lazy-loaded. In a perfect world, I would have a parent route at `/Index.html#details/<objId>` that holds all the lazy loaded data for each of its sub routes. When a user goes to `/Index.html#details/<objId>/tab1` or `/Index.html#details/<objId>/tab2` it can look at an object on the parent model for `tab1Data` or `tab2Data` to see if it needs to fetch data. Is there a way to do this with crossroads or maybe a better way to implement something like this?

Comment: Have you tried using [DurandalJS](http://durandaljs.com/)? It is a single page app framework that uses knockoutjs for data binding. Durandal has its own routing that facilitates deep linking. It also lets you do things asynchronously through promises.